# Does large size icon file take up large memory in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I use it in the following way with a .qrc file.

```
QAction* action = new QAction(QIcon(":/Resources/clear.png"), tr("&Clear"), this);
```

If clear.png is large like 128x128 pixels, does it take up large memory compared with small size file? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to go through the Qt source code to figure it out exactly, but we can give a worst-case-scenario upper-bound pretty easily:  an uncompressed 128x128 bitmap with 32-bit pixels would take up (128*128*4) bytes of RAM, or 64KB.  Add a bit more for overhead, and it's probably safe to say that the QIcon object created by the above code uses up less than 100KB of RAM.  Whether that's "large" or not depends on your personal definition of "large".  :)